# GTK 3 GUI updated from separate thread text countdown in text box

Tags: c, multithreading, raspberry-pi, gtk, gtk3

First post, so will try and be brief until need to add more. Ported an app from macOS to NI LabWindows/CVI, in "C", then to port to GTK3 and trying to grasp the updating GUI from external thread concept. I've read the gnome documentation and searched on here, and everywhere, but not finding similar usage, or not grasping the updating the GUI from separate thread. I have experimented with g_idle_add() as follows.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv); // init Gtk
    gtk_start_button = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder,"start_button"));
    gtk_main();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void start_button_clicked_cb(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    printf("\nStart Button Pressed\n");

    run_tests();
}

void run_tests( void )
{
    GThread *start_testing_thread;
    start_testing_thread = g_thread_new("", &start_testing, NULL);
}

void *start_testing (void *data)
{
    pause(5);
}

void pause( double pause_time)
{
    char    string[33];

    while( (double)pause_time > (double)0 )
    {
        sprintf( string, "Pausing %02.1f", pause_time );
        printf(string);


        //test_name( string );
        g_idle_add(test_name_gui, string);

        g_usleep(100000);   // uSecs for 100 mSecs

        pause_time -= 0.1;
    }
}

void test_name_gui(gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkTextBuffer*      buffer = gtk_text_buffer_new(NULL);
    char                temp[99];
    int error = -1;

    buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW (gtktextview_test_name));

    sprintf(temp,"\n%s gui\n",(char*)user_data);
    printf(temp);

    if(!g_utf8_validate(user_data,-1,NULL))
    {
        error = 3;
    }

    gtk_text_buffer_set_text (buffer, (char*)user_data, -1);

    printf("\nTest Name gui\n");

    g_object_unref(buffer);

    return G_SOURCE_REMOVE;
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that you pass a string allocated on the stack as data to a function executed later (test_name_gui), so the string won't exist anymore during test_name_gui execution. You should use g_strdup() when you call g_idle_add, and g_free() at the end of test_name_gui.

Comment: Change `g_idle_add(test_name_gui, string)` to `g_idle_add(test_name_gui, g_strdup(string))`, then add a call to `g_free(user_data)` at the end of test_name_gui

Comment: Thanks. I took out the text view and used labels, and there were some other parts of the code like changing button text that were not wrapped. So far everything is working now. I seen allocated on stack before for a solution also. No more crashes.